# Widget Errors on Newly Created Wordpress Site

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui

Good day, I had a newly installed wordpress site. There are no installed plugins or 3rd party themes, just the stock versions of Wordpress. However, there seems to be a problem before I could even customize the site.

It shows a lists of errors showing like a jquery/jquery-ui problem (or more, I'm not sure), if anyone had this kind of issues, probably you can help a brother out. I have exhausted all options on my end that even the clean installed wordpress wont even work.

```
Uncaught TypeError: o.widget is not a function
    at mouse.min.js?ver=1.13.2:11:163
    at mouse.min.js?ver=1.13.2:11:84
    at mouse.min.js?ver=1.13.2:11:94
draggable.min.js?ver=1.13.2:11

Uncaught TypeError: P.widget is not a function
    at draggable.min.js?ver=1.13.2:11:135
    at draggable.min.js?ver=1.13.2:11:103
    at draggable.min.js?ver=1.13.2:11:113
slider.min.js?ver=1.13.2:11

Uncaught TypeError: r.widget is not a function
    at slider.min.js?ver=1.13.2:11:135
    at slider.min.js?ver=1.13.2:11:103
    at slider.min.js?ver=1.13.2:11:113
iris.min.js?ver=1.1.1:5

Uncaught TypeError: a.widget is not a function
    at iris.min.js?ver=1.1.1:5:16724
    at iris.min.js?ver=1.1.1:5:16808
color-picker.min.js?ver=6.3.1:2

Uncaught TypeError: i.widget is not a function
    at color-picker.min.js?ver=6.3.1:2:3449
    at color-picker.min.js?ver=6.3.1:2:3478
accordion.min.js?ver=1.13.2:11

Uncaught TypeError: h.widget is not a function
    at accordion.min.js?ver=1.13.2:11:125
    at accordion.min.js?ver=1.13.2:11:93
    at accordion.min.js?ver=1.13.2:11:103
resizable.min.js?ver=1.13.2:11

Uncaught TypeError: z.widget is not a function
    at resizable.min.js?ver=1.13.2:11:135
    at resizable.min.js?ver=1.13.2:11:103
    at resizable.min.js?ver=1.13.2:11:113
controlgroup.min.js?ver=1.13.2:9

Uncaught TypeError: r.widget is not a function
    at controlgroup.min.js?ver=1.13.2:9:165
    at controlgroup.min.js?ver=1.13.2:9:95
    at controlgroup.min.js?ver=1.13.2:9:105
checkboxradio.min.js?ver=1.13.2:9

Uncaught TypeError: t.widget is not a function
    at checkboxradio.min.js?ver=1.13.2:9:140
    at checkboxradio.min.js?ver=1.13.2:9:95
    at checkboxradio.min.js?ver=1.13.2:9:105
button.min.js?ver=1.13.2:11

Uncaught TypeError: o.widget is not a function
    at button.min.js?ver=1.13.2:11:633
    at button.min.js?ver=1.13.2:11:93
    at button.min.js?ver=1.13.2:11:103
dialog.min.js?ver=1.13.2:11

Uncaught TypeError: l.widget is not a function
    at dialog.min.js?ver=1.13.2:11:187
    at dialog.min.js?ver=1.13.2:11:155
    at dialog.min.js?ver=1.13.2:11:165
menu.min.js?ver=1.13.2:11

Uncaught TypeError: a.widget is not a function
    at menu.min.js?ver=1.13.2:11:138
    at menu.min.js?ver=1.13.2:11:106
    at menu.min.js?ver=1.13.2:11:116
autocomplete.min.js?ver=1.13.2:11

Uncaught TypeError: o.widget is not a function
    at autocomplete.min.js?ver=1.13.2:11:147
    at autocomplete.min.js?ver=1.13.2:11:115
    at autocomplete.min.js?ver=1.13.2:11:125
sortable.min.js?ver=1.13.2:11

Uncaught TypeError: u.widget is not a function
    at sortable.min.js?ver=1.13.2:11:135
    at sortable.min.js?ver=1.13.2:11:103
    at sortable.min.js?ver=1.13.2:11:113
droppable.min.js?ver=1.13.2:11

Uncaught TypeError: a.widget is not a function
    at droppable.min.js?ver=1.13.2:11:186
    at droppable.min.js?ver=1.13.2:11:117
    at droppable.min.js?ver=1.13.2:11:127
tabs.min.js?ver=1.13.2:11

Uncaught TypeError: l.widget is not a function
    at tabs.min.js?ver=1.13.2:11:125
    at tabs.min.js?ver=1.13.2:11:93
    at tabs.min.js?ver=1.13.2:11:103
wpdialog.min.js?ver=6.3.1:2

Uncaught TypeError: e.widget is not a function
    at wpdialog.min.js?ver=6.3.1:2:16
    at wpdialog.min.js?ver=6.3.1:2:229
updates.min.js?ver=6.3.1:2

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'aysDeleteUninstall')
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (updates.min.js?ver=6.3.1:2:28397)
    at HTMLFormElement.dispatch (load-scripts.php?c=1&load%5Bchunk_0%5D=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,wp-polyfill-inert,regenerator-runtime,wp-polyfill,wp-hooks&ver=6.3.1:2:39997)
    at v.handle (load-scripts.php?c=1&load%5Bchunk_0%5D=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,wp-polyfill-inert,regenerator-runtime,wp-polyfill,wp-hooks&ver=6.3.1:2:37968)
```

The last one which is the ...

```
updates.min.js?ver=6.3.1:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'aysDeleteUninstall')
```

...is from trying to delete a plugin after it's installed. I tried to install a plugin from main wordpress plugin page but it didn't show any, also it throws an error as well. So I have to manually upload and install the plugin, but once I want to delete the plugin, it shows me that error.

Solutions tried:

- ❌ Install Clean Wordpress
- ❌ Cloned a fully working site to the domain (widget errors are still showing while on the original domain it does not)
- ❌ Enqueue JQuery and JQuery UI Script in functions
- ❌ Contacted Server Support to check the account (nothing unusual)
- ❌ Restarted Network
- ❌ Clear all caches (server sided, locally, browser)
- ❌ Installed a plugin to control Jquery/Jquery UI Versions
- ❌ Installed widget plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/jquery-ui-widgets/
- ❌ Manually added Jquery/Jquery UI Script in the admin
- ✅ Cloudflare cache purge ()

Probably there's a simple solution, I really need it.
Thanks in advance to those who can help.

Cheers~

Comment: Try looking at this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/9558891/10085052

It's likely the references to script files need to be reordered.

Comment: Update: The cause of the error was the cache in my cloudflare. (facepalm)

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution to my problem was to **PURGE CLOUDFLARE CACHE**

Comment: Could you elaborate how you purge the cloudflare cache and why it solves the issue?
Also, please mark this answer as the solution, since you posted the solution to your question by yourself.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).